# How to make a persistent parameter in a TFS widget

Tags: javascript, html, tfs, widget

I'm developing a custom TFS widget ( i'm very new about HTML & javascript).
I create a combo box parameter that set the type of a chart (Pie, stacke, bar, etc.)
The problem is that when i refresh the page, the value return to default.
There is a way to store parameters value so they are persistent after refreshing th page?
Thanks.

Below a little snippet:

```
// SAVE DATA
VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function (dataService) {
    dataService.setValue("MY_VARIABLE", MY_VARIABLE_VALUE, { scopeType: User" 
                     }).then(function (value) {
    });
});

// GET DATA
VSS.getService(VSS.ServiceIds.ExtensionData).then(function (dataService) {
    dataService.getValue("MY_VARIABLE", { scopeType: "User" }).then(function 
                        (value) {
         alert("Variable stored is equal to "+value);
     });
 });
```

Comment: can u pls add some relevant code ?

Comment: Please look at my update:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are server basic styles from the widget sdk for common form elements in widget configuration such as: Simple text box, Checkbox, Radio button, Dropdown, Multi-line text box

[image]

If the common box you talking about just the dropdown style. And seems you want to select a value, after refreshed page, the value will also change to the one you selected not default value.

You need to use **[Data storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/data-storage?view=vsts)**. VSTS extensions have the ability to store user preferences and complex data structures directly on Microsoft-provided infrastructure. This ensures your user's data is secure and backed up just like other account and project data. It also means for simple data storage needs, you (as the extension provider) are not required to setup or manage (or pay for) third-party data storage services.

> The service is designed to let you store and manage two different
>   types of data:
>
> - Settings: simple key-value settings (like user preferences)
> - Documents: collections of similar complex objects (documents)

More details about how to set storage please refer official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/data-storage?view=vsts#setting-storage).